# How to compute and sum gradients over multiple mini-batches in Keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I want to increase the mini batch-size for my neural network during training (instead of decaying the learning rate), but the upper limit for the mini batch-size is 8, due to my GPU memory.

I found this article

https://medium.com/@davidlmorton/increasing-mini-batch-size-without-increasing-memory-6794e10db672

on how to increase the mini-batch-size without increasing the memory, and it is doing that by implementing a DataLoader in PyTorch.

> The technique is simple, you just compute and sum gradients over
>   multiple mini-batches. Only after the specified number of mini-batches
>   do you update the model parameters.

```
count = 0
for inputs, targets in training_data_loader:
    if count == 0:
        optimizer.step()
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        count = batch_multiplier

    outputs = model(inputs)
    loss = loss_function(outputs, targets) / batch_multiplier
    loss.backward()

    count -= 1
```

However I couldn't find any examples for this in Keras. I assume that it would have to be done using a *data_generator(Sequence)*, in the function *__getitem__* ?
But I have no idea how to implement it, or if it is even possible in Keras. I tried looking at examples of DataGenerators as well, but none of them involved optimizers.
Would appreciate if anybody can help me out!